# Should I be implementing Equality for a Domain Service with Instance Variables?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see this link [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html). The author states: "Eric states in his book that services should be stateless, although we've talked about that and he no longer thinks that is necessary - although it's nice if you can do it"

Say I have a Domain Service that has instance variables (that are never mutated). How would I deal with Equality. For example:

1. Two entities are equal if they have the same ID
2. Two value objects are equal if all the members have the same value

Should I be implementing/overriding `.Equals()` and `.GetHashcode()` for Domain Services with instance variables that are never mutated?

Also, if a Domain Service was stateless then I guess there is no need for an equality method?

Comment: Can you explain a situation where you get two different instances of same service? And why would you want to compare them for equality?

Comment: @Euphoric, I cannot think of one.  If the domain service has no instance variables then they can only be compared by reference (meaning .equals is not needed).  Is that correct?

Comment: I would argue domain services should be at most, thread-local (or request-local) singletons. So it should not really be possible to have multiple instances of single service in same piece of code. So their definition of equality is meaningless.

Comment: @w0051977 what are these instance variables? Are they private? Could you make them `readonly`? Since they are never mutated, what makes you say that the service is stateful?

Comment: A service by its nature needs to be stateless as in not having a state that needs to be persisted. However you can have transient readonly state and that's ok. Anything that needs to persist _business data_ between usages should be a Value Object (usually as part of an aggregate involving an entity)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be implementing/overriding .Equals() and .GetHashcode() for Domain Services with instance variables that are never mutated?

Well, Fowler also points out [in the same article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html) that there is typically only one instance of a domain service in a given execution context.

> Service objects are often implemented by using global variables, class fields (monostates in Robert Martin's terminology) or singletons. Certainly they are usually singular, in that you only have one of them, but how you do that is more varied. Usually the singularity is within a processing context - so one per thread in a multi-threaded environment.

It would be very unusual for the domain code to care about the identity of the domain service -- that suggests that the domain has some interest in the underlying state itself, which will usually be expressed more explicitly in the code (ie, by giving the domain code a more direct connection to the state in question).

So I would be very suspicious to see an analog to an equality check ( sameServiceAs ?) appear in the interface used by the domain model.

A given implementation of a domain service interface might need `.Equals` or `.GetHashCode` to support infrastructure concerns, I suppose -- again, it is a bit odd given that there are usually only one of them around.